# Grouping by date is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four columns, ref, date, amount and running total and I have more then one record on a single day and I am trying to group by date so I only see one date with all the amounts and running total.

I have mainly tried grouping it together in different ways but it's not working how I expected.

```
    SELECT [REF], [DATE], [AMOUNT], SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY [DATE] ORDER BY [REF]) AS 'Running Total' FROM stageRecords
                WHERE [Accounts] != ''
                GROUP BY [REF], [DATE], [AMOUNT]
```

what some of the data looks like this:

```
ref    -    date  -    amount  -  running total    
1283    2018-04-23    -6769.13    338.46   
1284    2018-04-23   -338.46      5.6843418860808E-14  
109     2018-05-22    12328.58    12328.58   
110     2018-05-22    616.43      12945.01    
501     2018-05-22   -12328.58    616.43
```

Would like to see records with a single date with the amount and running total calculated.

Comment: if your 'ref' column have distinct values and you have 'ref' in group by, then grou by will not work as expected. the query try to group by 'ref' first, then by date and amount. if the

Comment: Then you need to do `GROUP BY [DATE]` only.

Adding both `[REF]` and `[AMOUNT]` in the GROUP BY clause will not make it to find records with same REF, AMOUNT, and DATE to group them together.

Comment: I agree that's quite funny. We read "I am trying to group by date" and see `GROUP BY [REF], [DATE], [AMOUNT]` instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Amount` from the aggregation, and instead use `SUM(AMOUNT)` as the quantity to be summed with a second `SUM` used as an analytic function.

```
SELECT
    [REF],
    [DATE],
    SUM(SUM(AMOUNT)) OVER (PARTITION BY [DATE] ORDER BY [REF]) AS 'Running Total'
FROM stageRecords
WHERE [Accounts] != ''
GROUP BY [REF], [DATE];
```

The above query makes sense, because analytic functions are set based, and are evaluated *after* the `GROUP BY` aggregation.  When the aggregation ends, `SUM(AMOUNT)` is available, and there is no reason why we cannot use it as input to an analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT sr.[DATE],
       SUM(SUM(AMOUNT)) OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) AS Running_Total
FROM stageRecords sr
WHERE Accounts <> ''
GROUP BY [DATE]
ORDER BY [DATE];
```

If you want one row per date, that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.